# Induction proof of divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I am trying to solve a proof by induction, which says

> For all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, 
>   $$ ((2n+1)^2 - 2^{n+1}(2n+1) + 2^{2n+1}) \mid ((2n+1)^4 + 4^{2n+1}). $$

Every try ended in a dead end. Does anybody have a hint?

Comment: You might be able to try finding the power series of both terms, then long division, but I doubt that's what you're supposed to do in number theory.

Comment: Where you able to confirm $n=0$ or $n=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that we can expand the right hand side as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(2n+1)^4+4^{2n+1} &= \left((2n+1)^2+2^{2n+1}\right)^2-2^{2n+2}\cdot(2n+1)^2 \\&= \left((2n+1)^2-2^{n+1}\cdot(2n+1)+2^{2n+1}\right)\left((2n+1)^2+2^{n+1}\cdot(2n+1)+2^{2n+1}\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Hence $$\left((2n+1)^2-2^{n+1}\cdot(2n+1)+2^{2n+1}\right)| \left((2n+1)^4+4^{2n+1}\right) $$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Is induction the way to proceed?

If you set $a=2n+1$ and $b=2^{2n}$ this states that
$$(a^2-2ab+2b^2)\mid (a^4+4b^2).$$
Is $a^2-2ab+2b^2$ an algebraic factor of $a^4+4b^2$?